# AlertDialog - Making it only pop up once

Tags: android

I have an alert dialog which pops up immediately after an activity has been started. If the user selects "Yes" the dialog is dismissed and the user can continue with the current activity. If the user selects "No", the user is redirected to another activity. My Question is how do I make it so that if the user selects "Yes", the alert dialog no longer pops up once the activity is started in the future. and if the user selects "No", the alert dialog should still continue to pop up each time that particular activity is started? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 final AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MonitorMain.this).create();
    builder.setMessage("Are you currently meal prep-ing?");
    builder.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            builder.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MonitorMain.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    builder.show();


}
```

Comment: You could have just updated your OP to explain this rather than deleting and reposting

Answer (score 2):

A common practice would be to save flags on your SharedPreferences. In your case it would be something like this:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
final AlertDialog builder = new 
AlertDialog.Builder(MonitorMain.this).create();
    builder.setMessage("Are you currently meal prep-ing?");
    builder.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes", new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        prefs.edit().putBoolean(DONT_SHOW_AGAIN, true).apply()
        builder.dismiss();
    }
});
builder.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MonitorMain.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});

if(!prefs.getBoolean(DONT_SHOW_AGAIN, false)){
    builder.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save a state to indicate the dialog has been showed once in the activity and the user selects **Yes** as well.

Add this code in **onStart** method

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    boolean shouldShowDialog = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("shouldShowDialog", false);
    if (!shouldShowDialog) {
        final AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MonitorMain.this).create();
        builder.setMessage("Are you currently meal prep-ing?");
        builder.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                        .putBoolean("shouldShowDialog", true)
                        .commit();
                builder.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MonitorMain.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }
}
```